# Is there a way to display json results in html in a nice way passed as a context from django view?

Tags: html, json, django, django-views, django-templates

I have my django views which returns a json and passing it as context to my html template but unfortunately i can't find a good way loop through all the results in the html template (which uses Bootstrap 4 cdn) in a nice format with their thumbnails. Here is my view

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from youtubesearchpython import SearchVideos
import urllib.parse
import json

def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.POST['video_name']
     
        search = SearchVideos(str(query), offset = 1, mode = "json", max_results = 10)

        ytresults = search.result()

        result_dict = json.loads(ytresults)

        

        context = {
            "result" : result_dict,
           }
        template_name = "youloader/results.html"
        return render(request, template_name, context)

    else:
        template_name = "youloader/index.html"
        return render(request, template_name)
```

in my template i tried to pass only the context key so i can make sure the results are returned as expected. and here is the sample of my template

```
{% extends 'youloader/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    <div style="padding-top: 20px">
    
    {{ result }}
           
    </div>
    
    
    {% endblock %}
```

and i have added the sample output
[image: result.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are passing a `dict` to the template the results are accessible with

```py
result.search_result
```

You can then iterate through the results in the template one-by-one to acces the thumbnail URL.

```py
# youloader/results.html
{% for video in result.search_result %}
    <img src="{{ video.thumbnails.0 }}">
{% endfor %}
```

From what I can see from the image `video.thumbnails` is a list that you can pick an index of 0 to 4 in order to choose the size of the image.

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately it doesn't work instead return error TemplateSyntaxError at /

Could not parse the remainder: '["search_result"]' from 'result["search_result"]'

Comment: Apologies @JAXPAROW95, I used the wrong syntax. I've updated the answer now.